# Javascript Ternary Logic Issue

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I recently came across a ternary logic statement in this form:

```
condition, condition ? condition ? expr1 : expr2 : expr3
```

I am not sure how to interpret this. I am not seeing anything on the web. Anybody got any info on this.

Comment: Hunt down whomever wrote that and play the worst 90s pop music at them until they learn to use `if/else`.

Comment: This is only a point of view @Quentin, it's not so hard to read, by the way, if/else can be unreadable.

Comment: @leaf except that the comma operator makes it completely ambiguous as to what original author intent was

Comment: @charlietfl There are many ambiguous stuffs when you learn programming.

Comment: @charlietfl And the comma is not part of the ternary expression :-)

Comment: @leaf what difference does that make? OP is asking about the whole expression and comma is part of it

Comment: @charlietfl Quentin and me were talking about the ternary operator, your comment was off-topic, that's it :-)

Comment: condition1,  (condition2 ? (condition3 ? expr1 : expr2) : expr3)

Answer (score 2):

```
condition, condition ? condition ? expr1 : expr2 : expr3
```

First you have a comma operator. This evaluates as the right hand side. So the first condition does nothing.

---

```
condition ? condition ? expr1 : expr2 : expr3
```

Then you just have two ternary expressions

It is the same as:

```
condition ? (condition ? expr1 : expr2) : expr3
```

So if the first condition is false, you get expr3.

Otherwise, the second condition picks between expr1 and expr2.

---

Never write code like this! Concisenes is only a virtue to the point where it makes it hard to understand what code means.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:)

```
condition1, condition2 ? condition3 ? expr1 : expr2 : expr3
```

condition1 don't parse. Let's use 'return' for example.

```
if( condition2 ){
  if(condition3){ 
      return exp1;
  } else { 
      return expr2;
  }
} else {
  return expr3;
}
```